# Particular Integral of $\ln(ax+by)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, multiple-integral

I was wondering what should be particular integral in case of $ln(ax+by)$.

In case it is homogeneous equation : 
$$P.I = (F(a,b))^{-1}\iiint \ln(v) \ dv\ dv\ \ldots$$
$$ v = ax+by $$

F(a,b) by putting values in differential equation.

Number of $dv$ depending upon order of homogeneous equation.

However, what would be P.I in case of non-homogeneous equation ?

Comment: Telegraphic style. Cannot.

Comment: Didn't get you there.